# Display “Sent” in the submit button after the message got successfully sent

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I was wondering if this is possible: I use a contact form 7 in my Wordpress page. After the user has completed the form an hit "Submit" I want to to have the "Submit" text changed to "Sent" so the user know has a feedback that the message went through. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent' , function( event ) {
    jQuery('#button-id').text('sent');
}, false );
</script>
```

Try this.